# Ag grid interactions/event

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-react

Ag grid has the following default interaction for the space bar:
**> Selection

> Pressing the ␣ Space key on a cell will select the cells row, or deselect the row if already selected. If multi-select is enabled, then the selection will not remove any previous selections. ``**

i would like to override the default functionality of the 'Enter' Key so that it performs the interactions which is assigned to the space bar by default

i have tried to find something in the api to create a custom event but no such luck